# JQuery UI icon-only buttons that POST

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, post

I have some icon-only action buttons on my application. The buttons are plain old anchor tags styled using JQuery UI, for example:

```
<a class="move-up-button-icon-only" href="/Ctrl/Action/5/8/2">Up</a>

$('.move-up-button-icon-only').button({
  text: false,
  icons: {
    primary: "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"
  }
});
```

[image: Icon buttons]

Some of the buttons have a side-effect, so I want to POST to the `href`.

I know I can use a standard `<input type="submit"/>` button, but then I cannot use the icon-only button, as JQuery UI cannot put an icon on a normal submit button. I'd really like to keep the visual consistency with my other buttons, so is there any way to change the method of an anchor link from GET to POST?

(It is OK if this does a GET request for browsers that don't support, say, Javascript. I will have a confirmation page in that case, and a regular form to POST.)

Comment: Do you already have a form that you can submit? Where is the payload of the post coming from? Are you working with an api that requires a post versus a get?

Comment: @Rob - No, there is no form. All of the parameters necessary for processing the request are in the URL. (This is an MVC application.) I am developing the API myself, so I *could* use GET, but it is bad practice to use a GET request for something that will have a side-effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, but it really feels like a dirty hack to me. Is this OK, or is there a better way?

```
$('.move-up-button-icon-only').click(function () {
  if ($.browser.msie) {
    var form = document.createElement("form")
    $(form).attr('method', 'post').attr('action', $(this).attr('href'));
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
  } else {
    $('<form/>').attr('method', 'post')
                .attr('action', $(this)
                .attr('href')).submit();
  }
});
```

Note that you have to add the form to the DOM in IE, other browsers just work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<button />` instead, no jQuery required for styling (though you might use it to attach button behaviors), and icon-only works fine:

```
<button class="my-button" />
```

...

```
.my-button {
    background:url('ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n.png') no-repeat left top;
    height:16px;  /* or whatever */
    width:16px; 
}
```

Semantically, if you're creating a button with no form, use the tools that you have at your availability - `<button />` *should* be what you want.

[Docs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).

Cheers